# how to get selected items in recyclerview with checkbox

Tags: android

how to get selected items in recyclerview with checkbox

[image: This is my example view]

for example: item 1,2,3 and 4 are checked. when i clicked the button create it will toast make text the item selected with their name.

This is my viewholder

```
public class UserViewGroupHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.image_account)
    CircleImageView mImageAccount;
    @Bind(R.id.text_contact_email)
    TextView mTextContactEmail;
    @Bind(R.id.text_contact_name)
    TextView mTextContactName;
    @Bind(R.id.check_box_user)
    CheckBox mCheckBoxUser;

    public UserViewGroupHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bind(final Account account, final User contact) {
       itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    mTextContactEmail.setText(contact.getEmail());
    mTextContactName.setText(contact.getDisplayName());


   }
}
```

And this is my Activity with onBindViewholder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewGroupHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(mAccount, mUsers.get(position));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> And this is my Activity with onBindViewholder

I suppose you meant Adapter, not Activity.

```
mTextContactEmail.setText(contact.getEmail());
mTextContactName.setText(contact.getDisplayName());
```

should be inside bind(...)

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Must be set not on itemView in Holder, but on "Create" button in options menu.
You can obtain checked state of particular view by few means. One* is to keep in User class boolean field "checked" with getter/setter, and write function with *for loop* on users list kept in adapter, returning list of users with checked state "true".
Naturally, checked state of user have to be changed in bind(...).

Toast with names for create button click is easy-peasy right now: your new adapter's function returns list of checked users (can return list of Strings with their names as well).

*Notice, this could make User class mutable if it was immutable before.

Oww and you CAN'T base your checked state knowledge on Holders or Views, because they're reusable. If there were many users (more than 10), such state would work on few ListView items at once, which is really poor.